# AdMob total requests disappearing and total revenue decreasing

Tags: android, admob

Surely I'm not the only one, but I haven't been able to find any explanation on here or with a quick Google search; I apologize in advance if this question has been asked here before.

I keep a daily log of my AdMob stats for my Android apps on the market, and I've seen a handful of days (sometimes consecutive) where both the Total Requests and the Total Revenue fields are going down.  Obviously the eCPM, Fill Rate and RPM will change [and possibly decrease] but how are the totals going down??  I wasn't sure if maybe these are actually projections, but I couldn't find anything stating such in the AdMob help, either.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I've seen just the opposite, actually... I get relatively low numbers, then AdSense numbers catch up and numbers from days past suddenly jump many multiples.

Comment: I also see a great fall in fill-rate and total requests since about a month, fall from >90% fill-rate to under 60%, I wondered if this had to do with summer period... of course when requests and fill-rate fall, revenue follows

Comment: @Earl that's kind of what I would expect, at least in comparison to Market analytics.

Comment: @Smugrik Wow--I haven't seen a the fill-rate go below 90% for any yet, but I've also only had anything on the market since the last week of May [this year].  Still, I would see that and eCPM/RPM going down but Total Revenue?  If the revenue was already earned, how am I losing it?  The field isn't for "daily revenue", which would make sense...

Comment: well of course total revenue is not gowing down, but revenue per week is, meaning total revenue is not growing as fast as it used to... Fill rate really fell drastically, since last month it didn't went over 80% a single day, and the average is now at 61%

Comment: I've got two apps... the fill rate on each is 75% and 85% respectively in the last week... and about the same for the last month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh, I just got what you mean by total revenue going down, weird...

I suppose total revenue is only shown for the period of time selected, if you view a 30 or 90 days window, total revenue going down means the revenue over that period is lower than it was for the previous same-length period.

Check "pending earning"s to see the all-time total amount on your account.

Comment: Hmm...I suppose you're right.  The "Pending Earnings" though is cumulative for all apps; would be nice to have the one listed for each individual app as accurate.  If I check the detailed daily report within AdMob itself, none of the daily revenue amounts are negative, so...looks like that's the best place to look.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the date range by clicking "Set table date range" and get the total revenue calculated from the start.